# ruby-debug-ide 0.6.1 or 0.7.x.x beta installation issues on a Windows 10

Tags: ruby, debugging, installation, ide

Even though I have debase 0.2.2 installed, I am seeing the rake failed message no matter what.  I am on a Windows 10 machine.  I also have the DEVKIT properly installed with the option 3 selected.  I used rubyinstaller-devkit-2.4.4-1-x64 as ruby version on this computer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z035F.png)
I wish the log message gave more specific info.  I also tried the --pre flag and other posts on the net to no luck...any ideas or recommendations.
See the attached image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will likely get better answers if you include the text of the error and reproduction steps rather than a screenshot.  Doing this will allow others who run into the same issue to find your question and hopefully an answer.

Comment: Here is more info:  C:\Ruby24-x64>gem install ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta4.gem --http-proxy http://proxy.xxxxx (Note I know proxy work because other gems install fine) Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta4.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta4/ext
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb

Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'debase (> 0)'